# How to tell user to publish first to share the latest version

Tags: user-behavior, web-app

In an editor, changes are auto-saved but when you publish the presentation you are saving a version in the version history. So how to tell the user to publish first so that when he/she clicks Share, they will share the latest version and not the second to last?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put users off by see <kbd>Share</kbd> disabled you can combine publish and share functions while pressing <kbd>Share</kbd> - first save contents in the version history automatically and then start share process.

My main point is that any explanations should be avoided - pressing button should be resulted exactly in what user wants to achieve by pressing it.

Comment: great tip! I can't up vote yet.I agree that explanations should be avoided. Thanks

Comment: @HenryR. If this is exactly what you are going to implement so you can mark this as answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following buttons in your editor: <kbd>Publish</kbd> and <kbd>Share</kbd>. Enable both buttons when loading unedited contents. Most probably your editor detects after each key pressed if initial text is modified. Use this flag to disable  <kbd>Share</kbd> when contents is modified or re-enable it if all modifications are undone.

Comment: Thanks,I thought of this option too to disable the share button although I wonder how long would it take to the users to understand this correlation.. I don't want to put users off  by see SHARE disabled.. I thought to have a message when they hover on the share button. So the UI stays clean but when they do go for share it says something " publish first to share latest version.
I have looked at other authoring tool, some don't need to Pubish changes they just save them so when you share you are always up to date. Other need to publish changes but warn the user of this inconsistency  too late

Comment: @HenryR. I posted another answer instead of putting it into comment as it is completely different with this answer.